# Delphi Class variable per class

Tags: delphi, class, variables

I've added a class variables to the base class of a deep class hierarchy. It's an integer intended to count number of instances created per class type. But I've run into a problem.

Given the example:

```
  TBaseClass = class
  private
    class var fCreated: integer;
  public
    class function NewInstance: TObject; override;  
  end;

  TDescendant = class(TBaseClass)
  end;

  ...

  class function TBaseClass.NewInstance: TObject;
  begin
    result := inherited NewInstance;
    inc(fCreated);
  end;
```

I assumed that I can use the class var to store the number of instances created **per class**, but this does not seem to be the case.

Inspecting `TBaseClass.fCreated` returns same value as `TDescendant.fCreated`, changing one via inspector changes the other, so it behaves as if `fCreated` is a single global var.

I expected `fCreated` to be maintained per class type, isn't that the point ? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are missing nothing. Your analysis of how class variables work is correct. A class var is nothing more than a global variable that is scoped by the class.

One simple solution for you is to use a dictionary to count the instances. A more hacky approach is to use a trick of mine that Hallvard Vassbotn blogged about, which (ab)uses the VMT to store class-specific fields. You can read all about it [here](http://hallvards.blogspot.nl/2007/05/hack17-virtual-class-variables-part-ii.html).

Answer (score 0):

You see TDescendant.fCreated as the same as TBaseClass.fCreated, becuse they are in the same unit, and therefore TDesendant sees the TBaseClass private fields. If you put them into separeted units, this will be over. Of if you declare fCreated not as Prvate, but Strict Private, TDescendant won't see it.